# JavaFX: Getting IDs of Dynamic created Button

Tags: java, button, dynamic, javafx

I'm currently made an Form with JavaFX. 
Always i press a Button, i call the "addAnswer()"-Method. 
In that I create a RadioButton, a Label and a delete-Button, which i bundle in a HBox. All that HBoxes i pack in a vBox. 
The Problem now is the delete-Button. I want to delte just THAT HBox in which the clicked Button is.

Here is my code:

```
public void addAnswer() {
    this.rB = new RadioButton();
    checkAnswer.getToggles().add(rB);
    hBox = new HBox();
    tF = new TextField();
    delAnswer = new Button("Löschen");
    delAnswer.setId(Integer.toString(counter));
    hBox.getChildren().addAll(rB, tF, delAnswer);
    hBox.setId(Integer.toString(counter));
    delAnswer.setOnAction(e -> delAnswer(Integer.parseInt(hBox.getId())));
    System.out.println(delAnswer.getId());

    vBox.getChildren().addAll(hBox);
    counter++;
}   

public void delAnswer(int e){  
    vBox.getChildren().remove(delAnswer.getId());

}
```

i tried this one above but i realized, that all the delAnswers-Buttons have the same ID: the number of how often i pressed the add-Button. 
Is there any solution where i can just select that one i pressed with that dynamic way? Cause i don't kow how often somebody will press or delete something.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hbox` is a field and this is why always the `HBox` last added is used. (`hBox` is evaluated, when lambda body is executed, not at the time of the lambda creation). This would be different, if you used a (effectively) `final` local variable:

```
final HBox hBoxLocal = hBox;
delAnswer.setOnAction(e -> delAnswer(Integer.parseInt(hBoxLocal.getId())));
```

However I'd like to present a different solution which would allow you to use the same `EventHandler<ActionEvent>` for all delete `Button`s:

You can get the `Node` that triggered the event using `getSource`. From this `Node` you can get the parent, which is the `HBox`. You can remove this from the `VBox` using the [`remove(Object)` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-java.lang.Object-)

```
delAnswer.setOnAction(e -> {
    // get button
    Node source = (Node) e.getSource();

    // remove parent of button from VBox
    vBox.getChildren().remove(source.getParent());
});
```

Comment: That was what I am looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you give the same event to all your button,Begin by creating a list that stores your buttons and then increments the value of the ID after affecting it to an item :

```
List<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<>();
/*
  Create Button and call IDEvt method to create new event
  for each button

*/
private void IDEvt(Button btn){

    btn.setId(String.valueOf(IDRank)); 

    btn.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {

            System.out.println(btn.getId());

        }
    });

    IDRank++;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but i don't want to add a new List. :)